# Show that ~ creates a partition of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Let $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ be the set of 2x2 matrices over $\mathbb{R}$: 
$$
M_2 (\mathbb{R}) = \biggl\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
\; \biggm| \; \text{with } a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \biggr\}. 
$$
For $M_1, M_2 \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, we say that $M_1 \sim M_2$ if $\det(M_1) = \det(M_2)$, where 
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = ad-bc.
$$

- Show that $\sim$ creates a partition of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.
- What are the representative elements of each partition?
- Are there countably or uncountably many distinct equivalence classes?

I am stuck and I could really use some help. I know that in order to have a partition, the union of all the partitions $X_i$ should be $X$ and $X_i \cap X_j = \varnothing$ for $i \ne j$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

- It suffices to show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $M_2(\mathbb R)$. So simply show that it's reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. This follows immediately, since $\sim$ is defined in terms of $=$.
- Try some examples. Pick a matrix at random, and find its equivalence class. Then try going backwards: pick a determinant at random, then try to find a matrix that has that as a determinant.
- From the above bullet, try to show that each $x \in \mathbb R$ corresponds to a distinct equivalence class $[M]_\sim$.

Answer (score 2):

Compute
$$\det\pmatrix{a&0\\0&1}$$
What do you notice?
The partition property is inherent because $\det$ is a function and $x \sim_f y :\Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)$ is an equivalence relation for any function $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we have a function $f\colon X\to Y$, we can define a relation $\sim_f$ over $X$ by declaring
$$
a\sim_f b\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad f(a)=f(b)
$$
This is readily seen to be an equivalence relation:

- for all $a\in X$, $a\sim_f a$: indeed $f(a)=f(a)$
- for all $a,b\in X$, if $a\sim_f b$, then $b\sim_f a$: indeed $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $f(b)=f(a)$
- for all $a,b,c\in X$, if $a\sim_f b$ and $b\sim_f c$, then $a\sim_f c$: indeed $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(b)=f(c)$ implies $f(a)=f(c)$

The equivalence class of $a\in X$ is $a/{\sim_f}=\{x\in X:f(x)=f(a)\}$.

Your case is with $X=M_2(\mathbb{R})$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is the determinant function.

“The” representative is not well defined. What you need is, given finding *one* representative, but there is no “canonical” choice. Since any real number can be the determinant of a suitable matrix, given $r\in\mathbb{R}$ you just need a matrix $A$ such that $\det A=r$.

Note also that, in the general case, one can define a map
$$
\bar{f}\colon X/{\sim_f}\to Y
$$
by declaring that $\bar{f}(a/{\sim_f})=f(a)$. This map is injective and has the same image as $f$. So, in your particular case, the set of equivalence classes is in 1-1 correspondence with $\mathbb{R}$.